# Concurrent Rehashing. What is "rehashed segment" in multilevel rehashing?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

Looking for an algorithm for implementing concurrent hash tables that don't rehash the entire table each time it needs to resize it I found the following paper:

[Per-bucket concurrent rehashing algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02235)

The "Multilevel rehashing" concept got my attention. The paper says:

> 2.3 Multilevel rehashing
>
> The drawbacks of recursive hashing may be addressed by extending
>   buckets with a more complex control field that indicates the number of
>   segments rehashed. So, any operation accessing an "old" bucket can
>   detect whether rehashing is necessary and move the data directly into
>   all the new buckets available at once as shown in Figure 3.
>   Nevertheless, recursive rehashing may be a better choice when resizing
>   is a rare event and there is no space for additional field in the
>   bucket.

But I don't get it. What are `rehashed segments`?

The paper later says:

> For multilevel rehashing, this check is trivial using information
>   about rehashed segments stored in the bucket, which in fact is current
>   capacity effective for the given bucket. The difficulty here is rather
>   in algorithm of detecting a correct root parent while other threads
>   can rehash it concurrently (not discussed in the paper).

Again, What are `rehashed segments`?

Comment: I may be missing something, but how, exactly, does your question related to C++, or C#? I see nothing specific to those languages, in your question.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It's related to c++ because the paper uses some pseudo c++ code. I would be happy with some c++ or c# code to explain things or give examples.

Comment: *explain and elaborate* is too broad for this site.

Comment: @JesúsLópez 1) Pseudo code is pseudo code. It doesn't mean to represent a specific language. 2) Sure, paper does that. I was asking how  does **your** question related to those languages? Especially, since C++ is quite different from C#.

Comment: @PatrickHofman. Edited, just ask what a rehashed segment is?